# Highlighting duplicates in Excel with VBA, multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a workbook set up with a sheet for every month and then a summary sheet, so 13 sheets total.  Each sheet, other than my summary page, have two sets of tables set up.  A table for each week in that month (named "Table_01_03" or accordingly for each Wednesday throughout the calendar year), and then also tables that give me totals for each week (named "Totals1" through "Totals52").  I am looking for a macro to find and highlight duplicates within column A (named "Part number") for the tables that start with "Table", then within the sheet, and then across all sheets that are not my summary sheet. I obviously don't want to include table headers or blanks, and I don't want to include any tables that start with "Totals".  I am still pretty new to VBA so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already ?

Comment: I have tried a few things.  I was using conditional formatting with the formula '=COUNTIF(SHEET2!$A$2:$A$50,SHEET1!A2>0)' in a different workbook then repeat for each sheet on each sheet (Sheet 2 referenced sheet 1, 3, and 4. Sheet 1 referenced sheet 2, 3,and 4, etc), but how I have this laid out it would be a new rule for every week referencing every other week.  Which is why I was hoping to make a macro.  I also tried setting up a scripting dictionary, but it wasn't highlighting properly.  I have been having a lot of trouble with it missing the first instance of a duplicate.